# run another application within a C# program with his childs

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi, process

I use a sample code to hunt process to my windows form application from specific List

```
void processStartEvent_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    string processName = e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value.ToString();
    int processID = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessID"].Value);

    if (_processNames.Contains(processName))
    {
        Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(processID);
        if (GlobalVar.SourceWinForm.InvokeRequired)
        {

            GlobalVar.SourceWinForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { ProcessHandler.SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, GlobalVar.SourceWinForm.Handle); }));
        }
        else
        {
            ProcessHandler.SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, GlobalVar.SourceWinForm.Handle);
        }
    }

}
```

as you can see i use the function :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hwc, IntPtr hwp);
```

everything work good except one thing.
for example i hunted notepad application into my app.
so it really give me the notepad into my app window but the problem start when 
i press for example in the notepad "Format -> Font" it open a new sub window of notepad , this sub window , my apllication is not father of this sub window.

how i can hunt the full process ? include his child (subs) windows ?

Comment: If you're **father of your son** then you cannot be also **father of his son**. In general you may reparent every child window of your monitored form but you have to do it in polling (enumerating his children) and it may also break target application. Step backward. Why do you need it?

Comment: i made a KIOSK application. my application block every thing in the windows when he is on to protect from user to do another actives except my application, then i supply to the user only 1 program that he can make it run and use. so i want this user will use only one application without to get outside to the desktop.

Comment: That's not the way to make a kiosk application...you have to replace default shell with your own application (it's a registry setting) and use policies and permissions to determine what users can do (or can not do). It's more _compatible_ with other applications and for sure more safe.

Comment: I know and you right. but the client wont do it in this way. so my only way is to make a normal software that simulator a kiosk application

Comment: `SetParent`ing a window belonging to an external process is a bad idea and rarely ends well. [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683/)

Comment: Unless you understand that [SetParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541.aspx) calls [AttachThreadInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681956.aspx) (and the implications of doing so), you should stop right there. Mandatory reading: [AttachThreadInput is like taking two threads and pooling their money into a joint bank account, where both parties need to be present in order to withdraw any money](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130619-00/?p=4043/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern
        bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern
        bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern
        bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);
```

and then

```
            // bring it to the foreground
            if (IsIconic(proc.MainWindowHandle))
                ShowWindowAsync(proc.MainWindowHandle, SW_RESTORE);
            SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
first of all i want to say the comments are correct and can help to someone else so please read the comments to my main question first.

but if you have specific scenario and you don't have any other option and you must use SetParent or other function like that. ( make  sure you read first about SetParent and you understand what it dose )

the solution is to take the entire forms to foreground:

```
bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

this make all the other forms that inherit from the main form you loaded to see it on your main application ( this in case you application block and streach entire screen )